# Delete row from room db

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, sql-delete

1.API call returns **5** items
2.inserts it in room db
3.Again calling the same API,but returns only **4** items this time
4.One item should be deleted from room db

How could this be done?

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
```

not working

Answer (score 0):

The above insert interface method will not delete your spare row.
What it does is that everytime that is going to insert an entity and that entity already exists (meaning that there is the same PK) it will replace the old entity with the new one.
What you need to do is

```
result = Dao()."Select * from _your_table"

result.forEach {
   if (it.primary_key_id.existsIn(response_from_server_list)) {
      Dao.insert(it)      // Will replace the already existed
   } else {
      Dao.delete(it)      // Will delete the rows that does not exist in server respone
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this logic is right i just want to know if there is an easy way than this

Comment: Well i cant think of anything else. I need to do the same to my app so i ll keep watching the discussion if someone has something more elegant and automatic..! :)